# Adding a fbprophet time series plot within a Bokeh dashboard?

Tags: data-visualization, bokeh, facebook-prophet

It's a bit of a strange question, but here goes.  I really like Bokeh dashboards for most things, but for time series fits and plots I think fbprophet can't be beat.  I was wondering if there's a way to combine fbprophet's time series fits and Bokeh's interactivity, so one could still for example hover around a point on a plot and it would tell you the value, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

The new [Panel](http://panel.pyviz.org) library is based on Bokeh but allowing you to compose plots from many different sources, and it may be helpful for you here. I haven't tried using prophet with it, and you'd definitely need something custom to connect the interactive events from prophet with Bokeh's.  Or you could stuff the prophet plot into a Bokeh Div without using Panel, and probably would have the same issue of figuring out how to connect the two of them up...